# View Twitter home page with PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl

I want to display some information on my website directly from Twitter. I know that there is their own API but what I need does not need all this since it is just information from the Twitter Home: https://twitter.com/explore

My code is just below I used to, but Twitter updated recently and now I can't.

```
$url = 'https://twitter.com/explore';

$options = [
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36',
];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

This code shows me the Twitter page but says it was not found.

> Sorry, that page doesn’t exist!

If I remove the `User-Agent` it shows me a page with the old version of Twitter but I need the new one what should I do?